# Using a queue for synchronous multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I have a python program which reads a line from a file, processes the line and then writes it to a new file. It repeats this for all lines in the file. Essentially:

```
for i in range(nlines):
    line = read_line(line_number = i)
    processed_line = process_line(line)
    write_line(line)
```

I'd like to multiprocess it so that one process takes care of the reading and writing and another process takes care of the processing:

```
read line 1 -> read line 2 -> write line 1 -> read line 3 -> write line 2 --> etc
              process line 1 --------------> process line 2 ----------------> etc
```

I guess that I would need to utilise two queues to pass the data back and forth, although I don't really know how to implement this in practice. Do you have any ideas of how I might split this problem across 2 processes using multiprocessing?

Comment: Does the output file need to contain processed lines in the same order in which the unprocessed lines are contained in the input file?

Comment: Yes thats right; To be completely correct, it needs to preserve the order in which they are read

Answer (score 0):

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue as mpq

def worker(qIn, qOut):
    for fpath,i,line in iter(qIn.get, None):
        qOut.put((fpath,i, process_line(line)))

def main(infilepath, outfilepath):
    qIn, qOut = mpq(), mpq()
    Process(target=worker, args=(qIn, qOut)).start()
    with open(infilepath) as infile, open(outfilepath, 'w') as outfile:
        numLines = 0
        for tup in enumerate(infile):
            qIn.put(tup)
            numLines += 1
        qIn.put(None)
        retlines = {}
        top = -1
        for _ in range(numLines)
            i,line = qOut.get))
            retlines[i] = line
            if i+1 in retlines:
                outfile.write(retlines.pop(i+1))
                i += 1
```

Of course, this waits to finish reading the input file before it starts writing to the output file, which is an efficiency bottleneck. I would do this instead:

```
def procWorker(qIn, qOut, numWriteWorkers):
    for fpath,i,line in iter(qIn.get, None):
        qOut.put((fpath,i, process_line(line)))
    for _ in range(numWriteWorkers):
        qOut.put(None)

def readWorker(qIn, qOut, numProcWorkers):
    for infilepath in iter(qIn.get, None):
        with open(infilepath) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                qOut.put((infilepath, i, line))
    for _  in range(numProcWorkers):
        qOut.put(None)

def writeWorker(qIn, qOut):
    outfilepaths = {"test1.in" : "test1.out"}  # dict that maps input filepaths to corresponding output filepaths
    lines = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    inds = collections.defaultdict(lamnda : -1)
    for fpath,i,line in iter(qIn.get, None):
        if i == inds[fpath] + 1:
            inds[fpath] += 1
            with open(outfilepaths[fpath], 'a') as outfile:
                outfile.write(line)
                qOut.put((fpath, i))
        else:
            lines[fpath][i] = line
    for fpath in lines:
        with open(outfilepaths[fpath], 'a') as outfile:
            for i in sorted(fpath):
                outfile.write(lines[fpath][i])
                qOut.put((fpath, i))
    qOut.put(None)

def main(infilepaths):
    readqIn, readqOut, procqOut, writeqOut = [Queue for _ in range(4)]
    numReadWorkers = 1  # fiddle to taste
    numWriteWorkers = 1  # fiddle to taste
    numProcWorkers = 1  # fiddle to taste

    for _ in range(numReadWorkers):
        Process(target=readWorker, args=(readqIn, readqOut, numProcWorkers)).start()
    for infilepath in infilepaths:
        readqIn.put(infilepath)
    for _ in range(numReadWorkers):
        readqIn.put(None)

    for _ in range(numProcWorkers):
        Process(target=procWorker, args=(readqOut, procqOut, numWriteWorkers)).start()

    for _ in range(numWriteWorkers):
        Process(target=writeWorker, args=(procqOut, writeqOut)).start()

    writeStops = 0
    while True:
        if writeStops == numWriteWorkers:
            break
        msg = writeqOut.get()
        if msg == None:
            writeStops += 1
        else:
            fpath, i = msg
            print("line #%d was written to file %s" %(i, fpath))
```

Note that this allows for the possibility of multiple readers and writers. Normally, this would be pointless, as there is only on head on a hard drive. However, if you are on some distributed filesystem or your files reside on multiple hard drives, then you could increase the number of read/write workers to increase your efficiency. Assuming a trivial `process_line` function, `numReadWorkers` + `numWriteWorkers` should equal the number of magnetic heads you have on all your hard drives. You could balance files on drives (*a la* raid) to reach some optimum here, but a lot depends on file sizes, read/write speeds, caching, etc.

Really, the first speedups you should get are from fiddling with `numProcWorkers`, which should give you a nice linear increase in efficiency, bounded of course, by the number of logical core processors on your machine

Comment: Thanks. I will try this out. Interesting comments about distributed system - I have been thinking that it would be good to then distribute this across multiple computers and have each computer processing a separate file.

Comment: Not managed to get this to work yet. You missed off creating a process for the write worker? In any case, it seems the library I am using for reading/writing is producing unpickleable objects, so I need a different workaround

Comment: @jramm: Sorry about the writeWorker issue. It's fixed now. If you make a new post about your pickling issues, you might get some help (from me or others)